# SSL Socket Connection implementation on IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, ssl, swift4

i am trying to setup a SSL Socket connection to my Server. I am new to IOS application Development. I didn't see any libs to do ssl socket connection. Kindly give me ur suggestions or comments to achieve ssl socket connection on IOS platform.

Comment: Are you using Swift or Objective-C? What have you found so far?

Comment: i am using swift 5. Normal socket connection working and Migrating to SSL Socket i didn't get Libs or dependencies related to IOS platform. No issues if your suggestion is in Objective -c also accepted. @sneeu

Answer (score 0):

I created a package written in Obj-C to handle sockets with iOS and the latest TLS restrictions imposed by Apple. Most important to the process is creating the certificates correctly, otherwise you will not be able to even make a handshake. I included a lot of good info for how to create certificates correctly in my `readme`.

https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/IOSObjCWebSockets/tree/master